# Problem with many to many relationship query JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have 2 entites `User` and `Role` with many to many relationship. I want to get `role_id` for specific `user_id`.

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Role> roles;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;
}

@Override
public List<Long> getUserRole(User user) {
    return entityManager.createNativeQuery("??????").getResultList();
}
```

How should I write query in JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you use createNativeQuery then you'll supply a native SQL query. If you want to use JPQL use the createQuery

To select the role_id by user id do

```
select role.id from Role role join role.users user where user.id=:p1
```

After that, you can do

```
entityManager.createQuery("query").setParameter("p1", user.getId()).getResultList();
```

Comment: @patryczek036 if it's solve your problem then accept the answer, thanks